# Meteor 1.3 mup deploy with npm packages

Tags: meteor, deployment, npm, meteor-up

Since Meteor 1.3 came out I've been absolutely loving the new npm packages support!

I've been running mup successfully, however when I upgraded to 1.3 and added some npm packages, I get an error when running `mup deploy`.

```
[server]=> Starting meteor app on port:3000
[server]
[server]/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:16
[server]    throw new Error('`'+ modPath+ '.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibe
[server]          ^
[server]Error: `/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.14/fibers.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibers`?
[server]    at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:16:8)
[server]    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
[server]    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
[server]    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
[server]    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
[server]    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
[server]    at require (module.js:380:17)
[server]    at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:1:75)
[server]    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
[server]    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

I am pretty certain this is because I don't have the modules I used in development installed on the server. Is there any way I can tell mup, or the docker container it makes, "hey, my project depends on these packages, install them to my project directory before you execute node.js!"

Answer (score 0):

Welp figured it out. So basically you need to run `npm init`! This will create a `package.json` file for you! That's what you need and it tells the server what dependancies your project has.